# Cloudflare pages deployment fails (React application with sass, sass import fails)

Tags: reactjs, import, sass, cloudflare

I am trying to deploy React application to CloudFlare pages. Before that I deployed it on GitHub pages and everything is working fine.

When I try to deploy on CloudFlare this is the error I got:

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

18:17:14.016      ╷
18:17:14.016    4 │ @import "../components/homepage/header/header.scss";
18:17:14.017      │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
18:17:14.017      ╵
18:17:14.018      src/styles/main.scss 4:9  root stylesheet

Anyone know what is the issue?

I tried setting absolute path also: @import "components/homepage/header/header.scss"; but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to troubleshoot without your project structure, but:

- Path typo.
- You may have changed capitalization at some point, so it won't recognize the new one.

Try changing the name of the file to something different, and re-import it.

Comment: Hi, no there is no type, when I run npm run build everything works fine so something is working different on CloudFlare pages.

Comment: Try setting webpackImporter: false, in your sass-loader options. See here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804#issuecomment-586095020